# How can I exit quietly from Elixir?

Tags: elixir

`Process.exit(self, :normal)` does the job, but it prints out `** (EXIT from #PID<0.49.0>) normal`. Is there a way to exit without the message?

Comment: I answered your question as best I could, but it's really vague. Can you explain what your process is running as well as where you are seeing the message printed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It depends on which application you are running. If you are building a script, you can invoke `System.halt(0)`. If you have an application, do not call `System.halt(0)`, as it will shutdown the whole system without considering all other applications. Instead use `System.stop(0)`.

Alternatively, you can call `exit(:shutdown)` to exit the current process. `:shutdown` is a common reason for exit in OTP and if you are inside `.exs` files, it will work just fine too.

Comment: Can I do this w.o shutting down the system? So I don't have to restart the server. More like `return`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. But the solution depends on the code your process is running (and where you are seeing the message printed).

If the process isn't using an OTP behavior and is simply a recursive function you could simply return from the function. Your recursive function just needs to have a case where the function doesn't invoke itself again. Something like this:

```
def recursive_function(:exit) do
  :ok
def recursive_function(other_clause) do
  ...
```

If your are using an OTP behavior like gen_server, all you need to do is stop that application that it is running under. This **will** print messages to the IEx console (which I assume is where you see that message), but it won't print anything to STDOUT, which I assume is what you are concerned about.

Comment: This is an OTP app. The code is here: https://github.com/ijt/speedometer commit 4cc3112e. I'm seeing this when I run `mix escript.build; ./speedometer -h`.

Comment: Just commented on that commit. I said a case statement, but you could probably use a if statement as well. As there are only two possible actions (do nothing AKA exit, or continue executing main). Hope that helps!