# How can I handle a broken STDOUT pipe in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

This Elixir script outputs some numbers.

```
# output_numbers.exs
(1..1_000) |> Enum.each(fn (i) ->
  IO.puts i
end)
```

If I run `elixir output_numbers.exs | head -10`, I get an error:

```
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :terminated
```

I think this is because `head -10` closes its `STDIN` pipe once it has 10 lines.

How can I gracefully terminate in this case?

Answer (score 1):

### Rescue ErlangError

This is a situation when `rescue` actually comes in handy. Instead of using `IO.puts i`, we could use this function:

```
  # For example, if user is piping STDOUT to `head -10`
  defp puts_unless_pipe_closed(data) do
    try do
      IO.puts(data)
    rescue
      ErlangError -> exit(:shutdown)
    end
  end
```

Here `exit(:shutdown)` is one way of [exiting quietly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994350/how-can-i-exit-quietly-from-elixir).